# Brief purple screen then display cuts out when installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, system-installation, usb

my problem is that when I try to install ubuntu 16.04 from USB, I briefly get the pruple screen with a keyboard and man(?)-icon on the bottom, then the display cuts out, whilst the PC remains on.

What I've done to troubleshoot this -

1) Tried booting from the USB on my laptop - got to the screen, and verified that there were no disk errors, which there weren't

2) Tried holding down shift when booting from the USB, didn't appear to do anything.

3) Booted into windows and it seems to work.

My system details:

```
Intel Core i5-760 LGA1156
Asus motherboard P7P55D-E
Ninja 3 cooler
ATX power supply Pentium p4 Model: PC- 750AUBA-B
LG ROM/DVD rewriter (Black)
Akasa card reader model: AK-ICR-07 (Black)
Aerocool Fan and Temperature Controller V12XT (Black)
VGA MSI N460GTX CYCLONE
RAM DDR3 
2x Corsair Dominator 4GB 1600MHz
1x Corsair Vengeance 4GB 1600MHz
HDD Samsung Samsung HD103SJ 1TB SATA 7200rpm 32M
Asus Xonar DG PCI 5.1 Audio card
Linksys by Cisco Wireless-N PCI Adapter with Dual-Band model: WMP600N (EU)
```

I suspect that it's the Nvidia graphics card - I was thinking of buying a cheap AMD r5 230 and if that would solve the problem I will happily do so.

Don't have much time till the weekend to do a proper troubleshoot, but I'm sort of at my wits end here since I don't see how to work out which component is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact the Nvidia graphics card. Looks like I had to go to settings by pressing Tab then going into nomodeset mode by pressing F6 and ticking it. Then when you've installed Ubuntu, you can install the binary drivers which solve the issue.